# How we made array of object from array of array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here I am trying to convert array of array to **array of object**.

Below is my code -

```
let arr = [["a",12],["b",15],["c",10],["d",19],["e",20]]
let resArr = []
let resObj = {}
arr.map(( ele,index ) => {
    resObj.label = ele[0]
    resObj.value = ele[1]
    resArr[index] = resObj
})
```

and I am getting output as -

```
resObj = 
[{label:"e",value:12},
{label:"e",value:12},
{label:"e",value:12},
{label:"e",value:12},
{label:"e",value:12}]
```

The last array content is copied to whole object.

Output should be -

```
resObj = 
[{label:"a",value:12},
{label:"b",value:15},
{label:"c",value:10},
{label:"d",value:19},
{label:"e",value:20}]
```

Please help me. Thanks in Advance. Please mention what is the mistake in my code

Please comment, how should I edit this question to get it up voted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create `resObj` inside the `map` callback; otherwise, you are modifying the same object in each iteration. Additionally, you should directly return `resObj` in the callback and use the result of `map` as the result array, as `Array#map` returns an array created by the return values of the callback after being called on each element of the original array.

```js
let arr = [["a",12],["b",15],["c",10],["d",19],["e",20]]
let resArr = arr.map(( ele,index ) => {
    let resObj = {}
    resObj.label = ele[0]
    resObj.value = ele[1]
    return resObj;
});
console.log(resArr);
```

For a simpler solution, you can use destructuring and shorthand property names.

```js
let arr = [["a",12],["b",15],["c",10],["d",19],["e",20]]
let resArr = arr.map(([label, value]) => ({label, value}));
console.log(resArr);
```

Comment: But in this case, "simpler" might well become "more *cryptic!"* If I were "an innocent programmer" who were now to follow you, I would consider the first version of your source-code much preferable to the second, because it would be much less likely to cause me to post to StackOverflow!  Quite seriously: ***"Clarity" is a "Virtue!"***  Microseconds really don't matter much anymore.  What really matters is that "the next programmer to follow you" *instantly* and *correctly(!)* understands you.

Comment: @MikeRobinson I posted my answer then saw your comment and I agree. It's a point we sometimes forget when answering a question. Though these cryptic solutions may encourage them to learn more.

Comment: Both of answers are very helpfull. I got my result.

Comment: @NarunDutta Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by referring to and changing the same object over and over again. You should create the object inside your map() to avoid that. By the way you can use a shorter version like this:

```js
    let arr = [
      ["a", 12],
      ["b", 15],
      ["c", 10],
      ["d", 19],
      ["e", 20]
    ];
    let resArr = arr.map(ele => {
      return {
        label: ele[0],
        value: ele[1]
      }
    });
    console.log(resArr);
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the intended result. `return` can also be omitted if you remove the curly braces.

Comment: @Unmitigated thanks, I missed the intended format. And about omitting the return{}, it is not working without it in the snippet! weird.